# Can't Access (Clone/Push/Pull) to Bitbucket after adding new ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

After I remove my old ssh key and added new key to bitbucket I cant pull/push or clone from/to bitbucket.

`ssh-add -l` shows the added key

After executing `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org` gets the following output and it waits indefinetly

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2406:da00:ff00::22c0:3470] port 22
```

Comment: The IP address `2406:da00:ff00::22c0:3470` is IPv6. You need to make sure your system properly route IPv6. If not — disable IPv6 and switch back to IPv4. See option `AddressFamily` in [`man ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config); set `AddressFamily inet`  in your `~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 1):

Check if the [firewall is the issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381605/7490), blocking any egress SSH query.

```
sudo ufw enable OpenSSH
```

Or disable (for testing) the [IPTables firewall](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/it-operations-management/network-flow-analysis/21-2/installing/system-recommendations-and-requirements/linux-servers/disable-the-iptables-firewall.html)

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

Try and [disable (temporarily, for testing) IPV6](https://www.xmodulo.com/disable-ipv6-linux.html).

Answer (score -1):

Just check your ssh config.

You can specify which privatekey to use for which host.

See also [here](https://superuser.com/a/232406)